# it's possible make a WP_Query with math operations?

Tags: php, wordpress, filtering

I have this situation. i'm building a WordPress site to sell some products. The thing is that the price of the products is stored as meta value, but the product price can be in difference currency. Now the problem is that I have to make a price filter for all product no matter in what currency is the price, the filter currency is configured in the background, and the the product that didn't have it's price in that currency have to be filter by the currency exchange tax, but i really don´t know how to build a meta_query were i can filter by currency equivalent price.

For example, I have this 2 products:

Product 1
-price:10
-currency: usd

Product 2
- price: 1000
- currency: xxx

the filter is set to use **usd** and find price between 0 and 10. So for this time the search will return **product 1**, but the currency conversion from **xxx** to **usd** is 500 to 1, the **product 2** equivalent price is **2 usd** the it have to be included on the search result.

until now this is the part of my code to handle the price filter:

```
if (
    isset($_REQUEST['max_price']) && $_REQUEST['max_price'] &&
    isset($_REQUEST['min_price']) && ($_REQUEST['min_price'] || $_REQUEST['min_price'] == 0)
) {
    $main_currency = cs_get_option('main_currency');
    $ex_currency = array_diff(['xxx', 'usd'], [$main_currency])[1];

    $args['meta_query'] [] =
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'price_meta_key',
                'value' => array($_REQUEST['min_price'], $_REQUEST['max_price']),
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'product_currency',
                'value' => $main_currency,
                'compare' => '='
            )
        );
}
```

but this only filter the product with the **$main_currency** currency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build up query that matches multiple currencies:

```
// Define currencies and exchange rates

$currencies = array(
    'usd' => 1,
    'eur' => 0.86
);

// Generate a term for each currency

$terms = array();

foreach ($currencies as $currency => $rate) {
    // Match the currency code and the converted price range

    $terms[] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',

        array(
            'key' => 'product_currency',
            'value' => $currency
            'compare' => '='
        ),

        array(
            'key' => 'price_meta_key',
            'value' => array(
                $_REQUEST['min_price'] * $rate,
                $_REQUEST['max_price'] * $rate
            ),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    );
}

// Finally OR the terms together

$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    $terms
);
```

Comment: didn't work with the foreach but I take the Idea and build the both query by hand and works perfectly